# Three.js with touch and or swipe events example

Tags: three.js

Saw this post already

[Iphone - Javascript Events...for three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307135/iphone-javascript-events-for-three-js)

But can anyone point me to an actual working three.js example using touch and swipe events?

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to this blog post WebGL may work on Iphone or Android but it's not really designed to...

Well, the next phone browser will probably support it, but, for now, WebGL is too young.
The unique solution to get full support seems to be CSS3d...

NB : Maybe Chrome on iphone can change this, you should check it out :)