# Select Mesh on Three.js

Tags: select, webgl, three.js

do you know how can I select a geometry with Three.js? 
ve you never seen something like that?

I searched for many days but all examples I found don't work and are legacy coded. I would have to be able to select a geometry with the mouse and move it like in a drag and drop.. Maybe better select a Mesh, cause there are a lot of composed shapes. It's not fundamental move it with mouse, I can do it with fields, so at least to know where is the feature to select a Geometry, if there is, I couldn't find it.. thanks

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292486/three-js-how-to-detect-what-shape-was-selected-after-drag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292486/three-js-how-to-detect-what-shape-was-selected-after-drag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select to color the mesh of the 3D model, use MeshLambertMaterial.js when creating the scene.

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html