# Three.js Raycaster collision detection with spheres

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I was working with an example from a previously answered question here: [Three Js Object3D Button Group Detect Single Object Click While Mouse Movement Causes Object3D Button Group Zoomi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157252/three-js-object3d-button-group-detect-single-object-click-while-mouse-movement-c)

I was making some changes to make it work the way I wanted, and ran into a few issues that I am having trouble figuring out.

Here is my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/agadiw/1/

1) I switched the objects from CubeGeometry to SphereGeometry and the collisions are not as accurate, it seems like I can only click on certain parts of the spheres to trigger a collision. The spheres are the same size as the cubes were, also sometimes when I click outside a sphere it triggers a collision. I alert a number unique to the sphere on collision.
Is there some kind of setting or position I have wrong?

2) When a sphere is clicked on, I try to change its color to red, however all the sphere's colors change to red, not just the one clicked on. I looked at what the intersects array is when sphere is clicked, and it only returns the one clicked on, I have no idea why it changes all of them.

3) Lastly, I have been looking for good resources, tutorials, examples, that are up to date or have good explanations of how things are working, but I haven't really found any I tried the official documentation, but a lot of sections just say 'todo'. I was just wondering if anyone had any just resources they could lead me to to help me learn this stuff.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The CSS `margin` must be zero in your case.

```
body { background: black; margin: 0; overflow: hidden }
```

Alternatively, you can see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div).

2) The color of all the objects changes because all your objects are sharing the same material. Do this instead:

```
ButtonsMesh = new THREE.Mesh( ButtonsGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
```

3) You are going to have to learn three.js by studying the examples and perusing message boards. Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/should-i-start-learning-webgl-or-use-three-js/11970687#11970687) for additional tips.

Comment: Thanks for the insight,Seems to be working now. I will continue looking through examples and perusing the boards. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using intersectObjects() to check the intersection. However the intersection therefore  includes all those objects. To fix it you need to loop through the objects with intersectObject() instead

```
 for (var i=0; i<=(objects.length-1); i++) {
     var intersect = raycaster.intersectObject(objects[i]);
     if (intersect.length > 0) {
         //change the color here
         break; //important to break the loop
     }
 }
```

As for documentation; These are good [examples](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/). But currently it's mainly digging through sourcecode and github to find what you need

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, I have tried what you suggested and it did not work. All the spheres turned red on click. I also tried altering inside the loop to see if I could figure it out, but still got the same result. Thank you for you help.