# Which Javascript 3D framework to incorperating?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

I want to create a 3D platform on which users can draw roads, mountains, rivers, cities etc. More or less similar (but less extensive) to Ceasar IV and Simcity.

However, the game is part of a larger website and the game should be able to dispatch events to eventhandlers so that other parts of the website can respond.

I have found [this](http://techslides.com/html5-game-engines-and-frameworks/) comprehensive list of 3d framework, but I'm somewhat confused about whether these framework can also publish events?

I understand if this question is seen an none constructive, but I have little clue of where to begin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't so much matter where you begin, just that you begin. :) You'll make some mistakes along the way but these technologies all use essentially the same underlying DOM apis. In particular, WebGL. I personally recommend THREE.js. This other stackoverflow discussion be relevant to you. [how to Get CLICKED element in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984471/how-to-get-clicked-element-in-three-js)

Comment: yeps, from all that i have seen tonight, THREE seems most clean. Allrighty lets code away!