# Solar system using Three js animation

Tags: three.js

I am creating a solar system using three js.In that I want to display some of the details on clicking on any objects.I have used object picking concepts.In that I am trying to get the objects which are intersecting with the
clicking.But I am unable get any objects which are intersecting.When I tried to print the objects in the intersects array I am getting as "undefined" and length of the intersects array as 0.

```
function mous(event) {
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
vector = vector.unproject(camera);

raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector);

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([orbitDir1,orbitDir2,orbitDir3,orbitDir4,orbitDir5]);
alert(intersects[0]);

alert(intersects.length);
```

}`

And here is the code for orbitDir.

```
geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(2.3, 100);
    geometry.vertices.shift();

circle = new THREE.Line(
    geometry,
    new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({color: 'red'})
);
circle.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5   ;
tex = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("Mercury.jpeg") ;
planet = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.3, 32, 32),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map : tex})
);
planet.position.set(2.3, 0, 0);
scene.add(planet);

orbit = new THREE.Group();
orbit.add(circle);
orbit.add(planet);

orbitDir = new THREE.Group();
orbitDir.add(orbit);
//orbitDir.position.x += 0.1 ;
orbitDir.position.y += 4 ;
orbitDir.position.z += 5 ;
orbitDir.rotation.x +=2.3 ;
scene.add(orbitDir);
```

Comment: could you provide a fiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

The code for »unprojection« and raycasting look fine, so I guess that the `x` and `y` values might not be right. You are using `clientX` and `clientY` which are the mouse coordinates relative to the upper left corner of the window. Those are only valid if your `<canvas>` is full page. If that is not the case, make sure to use mouse coordinates relative to the upper left edge of the `<canvas>`.

I think you can do the raycasting like that:

```
raycaster.intersectObjects(scene, true) //scan the whole scene recursive
```

[docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster)

Probably the answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984471/how-to-get-clicked-element-in-three-js)

```
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera.position );
```